# Chef : How to pass an array of hash to a resource

Tags: arrays, hash, chef-infra

I have to start multiple instances of tomcat using a chef cookbook. I want to define 2 ports in each instance - "http_port" and "shutdown_port".

I have defined a hash in my attributes default.rb as

```
default['my_cookbook']['instances'] = Hash.new
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How to mention the details of instances in my kitchen.yaml?
   .kitchen.yaml snippet

```
my_cookbook:
  instances:
    http_port: 8081
    shutdown_port: 8082
    http_port: 1212
    shutdown_port: 1234
```

2. How to pass the key, values for each instance to my resource?

Comment: Did you get any answer to  - How to pass the key, values for each instance to my resource?

Answer (score 0):

To override the node attributes in `kitchen.yml`, use `suites` feature.

```
suites:
  - name: node1
    run_list:
      - recipe[your_cookbook]
    attributes:
      my_cookbook:
        instances:
          http_port: 8081
          shutdown_port: 8082
  - name: node2
    run_list:
      - recipe[your_cookbook]
    attributes:
      my_cookbook:
        instances:
          http_port: 1212
          shutdown_port: 1234
```

For details, See:
http://kitchen.ci/docs/getting-started/adding-suite